# How to read Octave files into variables

Tags: csv, octave

I'm trying to load a csv file that includes strings into Octave. I found that the load function doesn't work on files with strings so I tried csvread. Though when I try to assign the result of a function it results in an error.For example for a file named churn.csv
csvread churn.csv will work without an error but
M = csvread.churn.csv will output an error "churn is not defined near line 1 column 1.
What could be the problem

csvread churn.csv

M = csvread churn.csv

Comment: It would be easier to answer , if you give a preview of your csv file.

Comment: Have a look at csv2cell from the io package

Comment: Add quotes  and brackets to file name: `M = csvread("churn.csv")`

Comment: @MichaelO. have you ever tried to read strings with csvread? This won't work, even with quotes ;-)